# Ingress nginx baremetal connexion refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I'am trying to learn kubernetes and ingress. I have misunderstood something ?

I using proxmox with 3vm

```
     kubectl get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k8sm    Ready    control-plane,master   127d   v1.22.4
k8sn1   Ready    <none>                 127d   v1.22.4
k8sn2   Ready    <none>     

        127d   v1.22.4
```

I Have 2 nginx pod as a deployment.

```
    kubectl get pod
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
curl-test                   1/1     Running   0          5d11h
frontend-86968456b9-jnbqf   1/1     Running   0          5d11h
frontend-86968456b9-tj2w9   1/1     Running   0          5d11h
```

1 service used with label

```
  kubectl get svc
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   127d
my-service-ingress   ClusterIP   10.104.228.72   <none>        80/TCP    25h
```

svc .yaml

```
    ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

I'm connected to the master node in ssh

```
 curl http://10.104.228.72
 THIS IS CONTAINER : 1
```

This is my ingress file copied from officiel kubernetes doc

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /frontend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-ingress
            port:
              number: 80
```

Ingress ressource:

```
    kubectl get ingress -o wide
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
test-ingress   <none>   *                 80      39m
```

info about ingress controler

```
kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create--1-tnglj    0/1     Completed   0          24h
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch--1-97n79     0/1     Completed   1          24h
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-547f579dc-ssf5r   1/1     Running     0          24h

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.100.181.85   <none>        80:32412/TCP,443:32016/TCP   24h
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.98.29.50     <none>        443/TCP                      24h

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           24h

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-547f579dc   1         1         1       24h

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           4s         24h
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           5s         24h
```

curl test with IP nodes don't work:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8sm    Ready    control-plane,master   127d   v1.22.4   192.168.1.38   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-18-amd64   docker://20.10.11
k8sn1   Ready    <none>                 127d   v1.22.4   192.168.1.39   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-18-amd64   docker://20.10.11
k8sn2   Ready    <none>                 127d   v1.22.4   192.168.1.40   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-18-amd64   docker://20.10.11
rbo@K8sM:~/elearning/kubernestes_admin_course/Zeal_Vora/Ingress$ curl http://192.168.1.39
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.39 port 80: Connexion refusée
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ingress you have used the path `/frontend` but you are not hitting it while

Also, use the `Node Port` with `Node IP` you are using internal service IP.

Something like :

```
curl http://192.168.1.39:32412/frontend
```

Comment: Hello dear thx for repply. Are you sure about nodeport ? it's say in documentation with ingress I must use ClusterIp. Can you please give me example of yaml ? I already tried with http://192.168.1.39/frontend and same result

Comment: i am not sure how your actual setup is if you are using out of network publicly you have to use Node IP, cluster ip only work internally in cluster

Comment: Got it dear, I have now with url http://192.168.1.39:32412/frontend web page with 404 not found page

Comment: Worked fine I added kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx in Annotation. Cannot fully understand why I should add port of service.

Comment: So now you are hitting nginx as you are getting the 404 error which will be form nginx side

Comment: clusterip is used by internal communication if you want to access out of cluster with Node port you have to use node Ip only.

Comment: Node Ip and Node port together expose the service to public while clusterip only resolve internally from another pod or service.